# Eclipse: Error in xml Graphical Layout after the new update

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

I updated the Android tools, etc from :

- SDK Manager
- help->check for updates
- help-> Install new Software...

It is actually an improvement with fragment now included when creating an activity.

I get this  error in each and every Graphical layout of every  xml[image]

Error Log:[image]

I added `layoutlib-api-22.4.2.jar` Add to build path in the project but didn't worked !

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its just nothing. Its takes some times to load when it will be refreshed. When it will be refreshed your xml file will be loaded.

Comment: Ya,It again & again refresh autamatically but then also gives the same error

Comment: layoutlib.jar is missing

Comment: @sur007 xml code is absolutely fine ! I have another workspace in which i have made projects previously. All It contains many code & the app also runs smoothly ! but cannot view graphical layout now in eclipse !

Comment: similar [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346234/layoutlib-jar-is-missing-plug-in-com-android-ide-eclipse-adt)

Comment: Can you pleasew try this once right click on the project in the project explorer and hit refresh to let it know Eclipse the file is there. You might need to clean the project and rebuild also.

Comment: Also try this
just right click the xml layout file and choose "Open With... Android Layout Editor". It seems to then fix itself until the next time.

Comment: @sur007 Not working ! the problem persists that each and evrytime I open the graphical layout of every xml then it starts loading 4.3,4.4,2.2,etc,and building workspace automatically & then it stops with showing the same msg as shown in the Image of Question

Comment: check this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627770/how-to-repair-an-eclipse-android-installation-png-load-problems-in-the-graphica?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, just changing the Android version to use when rendering layouts situated at top right corner avoid the problem :)[image]
Now I didn't get any error! :)

Answer (score 1):

The new update has a lot of problems 
the easy way is create your project from command line then import it to eclipse to do that:

1. Go to sdk folder for example mine is (The folder included android execute):

   $ cd Program/android/adt/sdk/tools/
2. Get list of target:

   $ ./android list

   ### Available Android targets:

   id: 1 or "android-7"
        Name: Android 2.1
   ...
3. Choose one of the target in that list and put the id in this command to create android project:

   $ ./android create project --target 24 --name MyFirstApp --path MyFirstApp --activity Main --package com.mrg.myfirstapp
4. Then it made for you. now in eclipse right click on project explorer:
   [image]

5.Select this:

[image]

6.Rename project name if you want and press Finish

[image]

then it may works

Comment: I have  no experience running android programs from cmd. I used to run java programs from cmd.

Comment: This worked for me when I checked "Copy projects into workspace" while importing the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ADT plugins

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the   following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Click OK and go on :)
   All the instruction can be found in the guide [Install plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: I already installed this ! & it is giving error that it cannot be installed again

Comment: If already installed then no need for re-installation just wait for some time it will be loaded automatically. You may get this message when you restart eclipse again

Comment: This problem arises after updating ADT plugins !

Comment: I thing problem is in layoutlib.jar, try to download latest layoutlib.jar and Add to build path in the project this might help.

Comment: I tried with latest `layoutlib-api-22.4.2.jar` but no profit