# layoutlib.jar is missing! : Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt, error-log

I am getting an error in graphical layout of xml after installing the updates from :

- SDK Manager
- help->check for updates
- help-> Install new Software...

[image]

Tell me how to get rid away from this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the api level(at top right of graphical layout) from 19 to 18 fixed this problem ! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can find that library for api 22 and upper [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlayoutlibapi2220jar.htm)

just add that lib to your project.